# Make Python Available to All Users When Already Installed only for One

Tags: python, windows, multiple-users, acc

So I have python installed for my main user account, but I need to use a clean account to make some videos. Is there a way to re-assign my current Python installation along with all installed packages to be available to all users on my Windows 10 machine please?

Comment: It'll be easier to just (re)install it for all users.

Answer (score 8):

Few steps for easy and better installation (As per 3.6,3.7,3.8 versions)

1 - Custom installation of python gives you more options.

2 - Do not forget to check ADD PYTHON to YOUR PATH.

NEXT

3- Ensure PIP option is checked and others as per your choice.

NEXT

4- Select install for all users and other option as per your choice

5 - Change the installation path

NOTE -  Some files have error in the installation , RUN as Administrator may work for those.

Below i have tried to capture view of installation window steps..

Thanks..
[image]

Comment: This was very helpful for me installing Python for all users on my workplace Windows machine. (Note to Windows users who have their machine access-controlled by their work: you need to run the Python Windows installer As Administrator as Hietsh suggests in order to install for all users, and in order to select some of the related options shown above.) Thanks!