# Is any solution for pycharm IDE?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have Reinstalled pycharm but still exist problem.
when I make new project and then make new python file it shows in message box that SDK is invalid. please help me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yrnpk.png)

I have reinstalled more than two times and have changed the installation path.

Comment: What is your version of python ?

Comment: my python version is 3.11

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid Python SDK in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70664467/invalid-python-sdk-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is that your path to your project likely contains a space:

```
path/to/PycharmProjects/Foo Bar Project/main.py
                           ^   ^
```

This means you may be able to do things such as install packages through the Terminal, but you'll get the SDK error afterwards. Once you Refactor the project directory (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> or right-click on the project directory and select **Refactor**) to remove the spaces in the path, you should be able to run without seeing the SDK error.